# MYSQL query to find the difference between paired rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working with MySQL and need a query that will find the difference between paired rows of a database.

DB looks something like this. There are two records for each Unique ID:

```
Name | Size

John | 10

John | 9

Dave | 10

Dave | 5
```

I need to find the difference in size between all paired records of a database. Outcome should look like this:

```
Name | Diff

John | 1

Dave | 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Size) - MIN(Size) AS Diff
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `HAVING` clause, he said there are only two records for each name .